# SOCKET select некорректная работа

Tags: c++, сокет

Решил перестать циклом проверять все сокеты на наличие новых сообщений, и объединить всё в `select`. Но теперь абсолютно непонятная проблема, которая заключается в том, что все сообщения, которые адресуются разным сокетам, прилетают в самый первый сокет в `fd_set` списке, что меня крайне не устраивает.

При старте проги очищаю список

```
FD_ZERO(&WinSocket::master);
```

После создания и проверки пригодности сокета отправляю его в список

```
FD_SET(s, &WinSocket::master);
```

(Все сокеты абсолютно новые, копий быть не может)

После чего запрашиваю сообщение, номер сокета мне тоже нужно узнать.

```
int index;
string response = WinSocket::fetchServerMessage(index);
```

Сама реализация

```
string fetchServerMessage(int & indexSock) {
    string res;
    fd_set copy = master;


    cout << "count: " << copy.fd_count << endl;
    int t = select(0, &copy, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    for (int i = 0; i < copy.fd_count; ++i) {
        cout << "i - " << i << endl;
        SOCKET &sock = copy.fd_array[i];
        int mret;
        char buffer[2048];
        mret = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if ((0 < mret) && (mret <= sizeof(buffer))) {
            res.assign(buffer, static_cast<size_t>(mret));
            res = UTF8::Convert(res.c_str());
        }

        if (res.size() > 1 && res[res.size() - 2] == '\r' && res[res.size() - 1] == '\n') {
            indexSock = i;
            cout << res << endl;
            return res;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Функция выполняется до `select` и спокойно себе ждёт, пока придёт сообщение.

Но проблема в том, что даже если сообщение приходит сокету под номером 5, то эта функция все равно найдёт это сообщение у первого сокета, и, соответственно, вернёт `index` равным 0, т.е. индекс первого сокета. При этом он не просто находит это сообщение у первого сокета, даже если я отправлю ответ, то он пойдёт не от пятого сокета, а снова от первого.

Как добиться той работы, которая мне нужна?

**UPD**

Окей, я запутался. эта функция работает как надо, т.е. получает сообщение тот сокет, который и должен его получить, и соответственно нормально отвечает. Только индекс по прежнему равен первому сокету, т.е. 0. Я запутался.

Теперь вопрос стоит иначе:

Как получить индекс активного сокета?

**UPD2**

Окей2, я распутался. Оказывается, select меняет тот массив, который я ему дал, именно поэтому в гайде было написано, что нужно создавать копию массива сокетов, и теперь понятно, почему у меня крашилась прога, если я передавал не копию. А меняет он массив на тот, в котором только те сокеты, в которые пришло сообщение. Всего 6 часов понадобилось, что бы разобраться. Кайф.

Итоговый код:

```
    string fetchServerMessage(int &indexSock) {
        string res;
        fd_set copy = master;

        int t = select(0, &copy, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
        for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
            SOCKET &sock = copy.fd_array[i];
            int mret;
            char buffer[2048];
            mret = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
            if ((0 < mret) && (mret <= sizeof(buffer))) {
            res.assign(buffer, static_cast<size_t>(mret));
            res = UTF8::Convert(res.c_str());


        if (res.size() > 1 && res[res.size() - 2] == '\r' && res[res.size() - 1] == '\n') {
            for (int i = 0; i < master.fd_count; ++i) {
                if (sock == master.fd_array[i])
                    indexSock = i;
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Вообщем я понял, что больше с сокетами работать не буду. А ещё я понял, что **не нужно улучшать то, что и так прекрасно работает**.

Comment: У вас винда, что ли?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых результат `select`, то бишь количество готовых сокетов, игнорируется.

Во-вторых, проверять, готов сокет или нет следует вызовом макроса `FD_ISSET`, никакого индекса получать не надо:

```
if(0 != FD_ISSET(s, &copy))
{
   // Пытаемся читать...
}
```

В-третьих, может быть готово несколько сокетов.